# Comparison between contrasts in emmeans

Tags: contrasts, lsmeans

Let's say I have these estimated marginal means:

```
> emm <- emmeans(Model5, ~ Measurement * Condition)
> emm
 Measurement Condition emmean     SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 B           L           7.98 0.0474 1788     7.89     8.07
 1           L           7.97 0.0474 1788     7.88     8.06
 2           L           8.04 0.0474 1788     7.95     8.14
 B           N           7.96 0.0474 1788     7.87     8.05
 1           N           8.00 0.0474 1788     7.91     8.10
 2           N           7.93 0.0474 1788     7.84     8.03
```

I want to check for significance, insider condition N: B vs 1 compared to B vs 2.

How can I do that?

I only found a way to do straightforward contrasts:

```
contrast(emm, list(
  "N_B vs N_1 " = c(0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
))
```

but not to do a comparison between two contrasts.

Answer (score 0):

See [this vignette section](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html#contrasts)

And in general, there is an [index to all the vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/vignette-topics.html) in the **emmeans** package, and you can often find answers to questions like this.

But a quick answer to thgis question is

```
contrast(emm, interaction = "consec")
```

which constructs all interaction contrasts involving consecutive levels of each factor.